# How to recover the deleted records from sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with records, some of the records has been deleted. I need to recover those record from this database, Is it possible to recover ? anyone can help me?

Comment: Not possible unless you backed them up somehow.

Comment: Ok,If i open this database file using TextEdit, I can see the deleted record content in that file.But i don't know how to retrieved it and don't know in which file struct format it has been saved.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Can you rephrase?